# How do I get a Belkin F5D6050 wireless USB network adapter to work?

Tags: installation, wireless, usb, internet-connection, adapter

The title question says it all.

I've been working to answer it for my computer for the last 12 hours. I've read many articles, attempted many tricks and am more or less where I was with this problem at the start.

I won't waste breath here citing a bunch of info that may not be needed to resolve the issue, so I'll just follow the title question with this: What do you need to know about my setup, hardware, software or experience to help me (and struggling users like me) get at a solution?

Thanks in advance.

+Ralston

**UPDATE**: Jan 9

At the direction of fossfreedom I'm sharing the output of multiple terminal commands.

---

Command: `rfkill list all`

USB Adaptor: Plugged in.

Yield: Absolutely nothing. *(Entered this command multiple times to make sure I was getting it right. Each time no result was returned by the terminal.)*

---

Command: `sudo lshw -class network`

USB Adaptor: Plugged in.

Yield: Displays `PCI (sysfs)` for just a few seconds then produces the following:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: f
       bus info: pci@0000:02:0f.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 00:0e:a6:42:ba:24
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=8139too driverversion=0.9.28 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.88 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:b800(size=256) memory:feafec00-feafecff
```

---

Command: `lsusb`

USB Adaptor: Plugged in.

Yield:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 050d:0050 Belkin Components F5D6050 802.11b Wireless Adapter v2000 [Atmel at76c503a]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
```

---

Command: `dmesg`

USB Adaptor: Plugged in and unplugged.

Yield: This command displays quite a bit of data. I pasted it all here--both the results from when the device was plugged in and unplugged. However, when I attempted to post the updates to my question here with all that data, I got this "Oops" message: "body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 74516." If this info is really needed to help troubleshoot my problem, I think I'm going to need another way to post it. Or, if there is a particular line or set of lines that is most important in the results of the `dmesg` command, please let me know and I'll look for it and add it here.

UPDATE: Jan 9

Used the paste.ubuntu.com service for the dmesg command results. Both unplugged and plugged in results can be seen below.

---

Command: `dmesg`

USB Adaptor: Unplugged.

Yield: [Pasted Unplugged Results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/798306/)

This command displays a lot of data. I'm not sure if the Terminal has some line limit, but it looks as if the results of this command exceeded that limit. If it is necessary, please let me know if there is some way to pause the results like `dir /P` in DOS.

---

Command: `dmesg`

USB Adaptor: Plugged in.

Yield: [Pasted Plugged-in Results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/798307/)

I haven't got through each line to note any differences (not even sure what I'd be looking for), but here are the results.

Comment: Thank you, fossfreedom, for chiming in. But there's quite a bit of content at that link you provided. It would be most helpful if you (or anyone) can tell me directly what specifically you need me to report here. Might save a bit of guessing on my end and sifting on yours.

Comment: I'm sorry, fossfreedom, there must be some disconnect then. When I access the link you provided, I see at least 8 answers to one broad question. Many of those answers seem to "depend" on the situation. My situation is quite specific so I'm betting some of those answers and suggestions won't prove necessary. If you can direct me to some part of that page's content, I'd be happy to provide whatever info or logs you need.

Comment: plug in your usb device.  In a terminal we need to see the output of the following commands: `rfkill list all` , `sudo lshw -class network` , `lsusb`.  Also, disconnect your usb device, type `dmesg` - plug in your usb device, type `dmesg` - you should see some new output.  we need to see that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, fossfreedom. Very clear directions. I've updated my question with the results from the commands you cited as best I could.

Comment: ok - worrying that there is no response to rfkill nor lshw.  Need to have a look at dmesg - please use paste.ubuntu.com and copy and paste the url into your question.

Comment: ... in the dmesg there should be line/lines stating that it needs firmware - this whole section is required (whether it finds the firmware or whether it fails to find the firmware).

Comment: Sorry, just saw your note. I added the links to the pasted results per your instructions. Please let me know if this isn't what I needed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of you trace is the following error message:

```
usb 2-1: new full speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
    [ 3335.676636] usb 2-1: firmware atmel_at76c503-rfmd.bin not found!
    [ 3335.676645] usb 2-1: you may need to download the firmware from http://developer.berlios.de/projects/at76c503a/
    [ 3335.676663] at76c50x-usb: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -2
```

Therefore, download the firmware file from the website: http://developer.berlios.de/projects/at76c503a/

Then in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvf at76_usb-firmware-0.1.tar.gz
cd at76_usb-firmware-0.1/
sudo cp *.bin /lib/firmware
```

Logout and login.  Hopefully now your wireless card is now recognised.

Comment: Thank you, fossfreedom. That was most helpful. After restarting my computer the Belkin F5D6050 is now recognized. For the first time I am able to see available networks around me. Of course, this reveals a new problem. Every available network listed, including my own, shows a rather nonexistent signal strength. So I can see the SSID for my network, but I can't successfully connect to it. I find that odd, but hope it's just another simple setup step I'm missing. Like maybe my antenna is disabled somehow. Ideas?

Comment: if its a different question - then ask it... otherwise if its directly applicable, edit your question.  If its the former - please click the tick button to accept.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My comment was submitted before I was finished writing. I'd say it's directly applicable since I'm still just trying to get the device to 'work' correctly.

Comment: ... ok - its worth playing with the router channel number 0, 6, 13 etc as well as no-security, wep, WPA etc.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Channel changing did nothing for me, but removing the router's security (WPA-PSK (TKIP) and WPA2-PSK (AES)) got me in. When I restablished the security settings on the router I could not connect again. Does that mean I can't use my router's wireless security settings if I'm going to use this USB adapter?

Comment: I dont know much about the Belkin device... is it capable of WPA?  Maybe its limited to WEP.  Also, be very careful with case sensitivity - on my wireless I have to have my WPA security code all in uppercase - i.e. a `abc` is not the same as `ABC`

Comment: You've been awesome, fossfreedom. I think you're right and that it's an issue of capability. I'm going to call this problem solved as your great help has gotten as far as I can go with this Belkin F5D6050. Thanks for your knowledge, willingness and patience.